# Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Error in devtools:

> [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive

What's the matter?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ajax-service').keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      url: "{% url 'ajax_request' %}",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.is_exist) {
          console.log("TYT");
          let list = ''
          
          for (var i in response.is_taken) {
            list = list + '<span name="' + (response.is_taken[i]) + '" id="' + (i) + '">' + (response.is_taken[i]) + '</span> '
          }
          
          //console.log("i: "+i);
          //let elem_input = document.querySelector("ajax-service")
          //let elem = document.querySelector("#service"+i);
          //console.log("response: "+response.is_taken[i]);
          //console.log("elem: "+elem);
          
          $('#ajax-service-list').remove();
          $('#ajax-service').after('<div id="ajax-service-list" name="ajax-service-list">' + (list) + '</div>')
        } else {
          $('#ajax-service-list').remove();
          $('#ajax-service').after('<div id="ajax-service-list" name="ajax-service-list"><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark" id="ajax-service-list">Нет совпадений</span></div>')
        }
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response.responseJSON.errors)
      }
    });
    
    return false;
  });
})
```

**upd:**

[image]

Comment: The code you've shown does not cause the error in the question. The error in devtools should point to the specific line which caused the exception.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I added a picture, can you see it?

Comment: The error is not coming from the code. If you click on the error message where in the code does it take you to?